# Get the server response in WebSocket

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I use this code for a WebSocket API which subscribes to the tables:

```
$("#testing").click(function(){
  var subscribe = JSON.stringify({
    "$type": "subscribe"
  });
});
```

This is the WebSocket code:

```
var sock = new WebSocket("wss://example");
sock.send(respond);
```

The response is something like this: `{"name","A","ID",3}`

How can I send the response of that into a string. For example:

```
var a = <Response of the subscription>;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is missing **any** WebSocket relation. Give us more information, so we can help you with this problem of yours.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. `subscribe` is already a string - see http://jsfiddle.net/xvcq4zsy/ . So, please explain what else exactly you wish to achieve?

Comment: @CodiMech25 I updated the question

Comment: @ADyson Subscribe is string but I want to get the respond of that as string. See the updated question

Comment: " get the respond of that" means what? A string such as `subscribe` doesn't have a response. It's just a string. Are you really asking how to receive messages from your websocket? It's not clear how that relates to the `subscribe` string, but I imagine if you follow a tutorial or other example it will show you the basics.

Comment: @Developer Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Comment: @CodiMech25 It only shows Undefined